# How to print a message of number of rows from a table variable name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to print out the number of rows when given only a variable named *after* the table and not the actual table name itself. Below is my attempt to make this work. It should print out to the message box of SQL Server "X" number of rows.

```
DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @tableName = 'Tb_Offers' --Name of table i need to find the number of rows therin

DECLARE @rowCount AS INT --variable to store count of rows
SELECT @rowCount = COUNT(*) FROM @tableName

PRINT @rowCount --statement to print count to MS SQL message box.
```

Comment: You can't use a variable for a tablename without using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Never `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <anything>;` to get a count. Try:

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname = N'Tb_Offers';

SELECT @rowCount = SUM(rows)
  FROM sys.partitions
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.' 
    + QUOTENAME(@tableName))
  AND index_id IN (0,1);
```

Additionally:

1. Object names are `sysname` or `nvarchar(128)`, not `varchar(100)`, and strings that contain entity names need to be prefixed with `N`. Use the system metadata correctly to avoid getting burned.
2. Stop [counting rows the hard way](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way); there is zero reason to read an entire table to get the number of rows.

Comment: Is this accurate? I notice in the documentation that [rows] "Indicates the approximate number of rows in this partition."

Comment: @George Yes, it is accurate. Notice that I use a `SUM` to aggregate across all partitions and I only look at either the heap or the clustered index. As for what "approximate" really means, please [read the link](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way). If neither of those is what you mean, please clarify what you mean by "accurate"...

Comment: Good stuff. Gonna wrap this in a procedure for ease of use.